# Paypal express checkout error 10007: Permission denied

Tags: php, paypal

I have integrated the Paypal express checkout in my site and it was working in sandbox mode.
Then i changed it live mode with live credentials.

Now i getting success response,token and  payer id after calling 'SetExpressCheckout'

But after i call 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment', iam getting  an error

10007: Permission denied
You do not have permissions to make this API call

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013%2d08%2d29T04%3a06%3a19Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => dd49ea1655d2c
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 76%2e0
    [BUILD] => 7507921
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10007
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Permission%20denied
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You%20do%20not%20have%20permissions%20to%20make%20this%20API%20call
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

What may be the reason for this type of error, any idea ?

Comment: According to call to paypal customer support.They saying that indian customer can't pay through the paypal express checkout .That May be my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was related to Paypal Merchant account.
That account was blocked by Paypal.
Now we created  new paypal account and its working fine.Nothing was related to code